# Alternating Conditional Expectations: Multiple regression transform

Tags: regression, data-transformation, nonparametric, conditional-expectation

Alternating Conditional Expectations (ACE) is a non-parametric algorithm  for multiple regression transform selection. It finds a set of transformed response variables that maximizes $R^2$ using smoothing functions.

What kind of transformations can be found, loosely, what is the transformation space? So for example could it potentially output the logarithm of the dependent variable?

Is the ACE algorithm mainly used as an intermediate step in regression analysis, to hint at transformations, or is it used directly to give results? Further what is the ACE algorithm’s relationship with additive models?

I am interested in this as an extra tool to use in regression analyses or in any other way suggested in the comments or answers.

Comment: Alternating not alternative. The key source is Breiman, L. and Friedman, J. H. 1985. Estimating optimal transformations for multiple regression and correlation. _J. Am. Stat. Assoc._  80: 580–598. I don't see ACE mentioned much recently, but that could easily be down to my personal reading.

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the correction and the key source. There is perhaps not much contemporary mention of ACE, and I was thinking why this would be as it seems potentially useful either for finding transforms in regression analysis or perhaps for more broader exploratory data analysis.

Comment: I’ve never used it. I would regard it as in practice superseded by or subsumed within frameworks under headings like generalized additive models.

Comment: @NIckCox this helpful. GAM would be more flexible and likely have advantages in terms of supplementary methods like goodness of fit. Maybe ACE has advantages in terms of relative simplicity.

Comment: The main potential advantage for ACE as I see it is in the flexibility of choices of transformation of the response to something that is approximately additive in the predictors (compared to typical choices of link function). In terms of the predictors, it's then doing essentially the same job as additive models do.

Comment: @Glen_b I think one of the things you are saying is that if we compare to a GLM then the ACE model avoids the complication of a link function? The Wikipedia article on AMs mentions that they are more interpretable than a “general regression surface” which I interpret to mean a link function but it is unclear if this is the case.

Comment: A link function is not the same thing as a regression surface. A link function would be akin to the ACE transformation of the response, in that ACE's $E(g(y))$   is approximately GAM's $g(E(y))$ (I say GAM rather than GLM since in ACE we transform the predictors to approximately additive functions)